# What is the best way to convert an int or null to boolean value in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, null, boolean, type-conversion

What is the best way to convert an int or null to boolean value in an SQL query, such that:

- Any non-null value is **TRUE** in the results
- Any null value is **FALSE** in the results

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To my knowledge (correct me if I'm wrong), there is no concept of literal boolean values in SQL. You can have expressions evaluating to boolean values, but you cannot output them.

This said, you can use CASE WHEN to produce a value you can use in a comparison:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ValueColumn IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END BooleanOutput 
FROM 
    table
```

Comment: To make it easier to consume the result in code, I prefer returning a bit value where - semantically - a boolean is expected.

Comment: BIT has it's own pitfalls (at least it T-SQL). It is not a real boolean data type (internally, a bit mask is used to store the values as a union). This has performance and indexing implications. Using CHAR(1) or INT might be more wise.

Comment: Additionally, for SQL Server: "The string values 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' can be converted to bit values: 'TRUE' is converted to 1 and 'FALSE' is converted to 0."

Comment: Using a varchar when OP explicitly asks for a boolean doesn't seem to be the correct solution. You should at least show how to return a `bit`. Because that is the `Boolean` type mapping from sql-server to .NET. [Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter My answer outlines that you, and I quote, *"can use CASE WHEN to produce a value you can use"*. Nowhere do I imply that it has to be VARCHAR. Also what .NET mappings have to do with anything here is not really clear.

Comment: @Tomalak: OP wants to return a `bool`. Since there is no real bool type that you can return the nearest in sql-server is `bit`. That is also the data type that you _have to_ use when you want to read it as `bool` without conversion in most languages like C++, .NET or java. So it seems to be relevant. Also, since the title asks for a conversion between `int` to `bool` it would be helpful for future readers to show `CAST(CASE WHEN ValueColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS BooleanOutput`.

Comment: @Tim I understand your point, but it's an implementation detail that is part or the relation of SQL and, say, .NET. Using the BIT datatype is not any closer to a true Boolean than the CHAR(1) `'Y'`and `'N'` would be. The core point of the whole thing is that T-SQL does not have Booleans and that you need to use some sort of convention to represent them. This convention might be influenced by the language you are interacting with - maybe C#, maybe something else - and has nothing to do with SQL itself. Your "CASE WHEN"-is exactly equivalent to mine. ;)

Answer (score 32):

No need to use case... when:

```
select (column_name is not null) as result from table_name;
```

Returns 1 for all fields not NULL and 0 for all fields that are NULL, which is as close as you can get to booleans in SQL.

Comment: isnull() needs a second parameter in T-SQL: ISNULL(value, value-if-null)

Comment: '(not column_name is null)' is no valid expression either. ;-)

Comment: It may work for MySQL, but a lot strange 'convenience' syntax works for MySQL that does not run elsewhere.

Comment: "is null" is a perfectly valid predicate in ANSI SQL.  Thi should work everywhere (_should_!)

Comment: iirc the correct t-sql syntax would be: "column_name not is null" or "is not null" or something like that

Comment: Not quite. 'ColumnName IS NOT NULL' is the correct syntax. T-SQL has nothing to do with it, this ist standard SQL.

Comment: did you try "NOT (column_name IS NULL)"?

Comment: @Lette: Neither '(column_name IS NULL)' nor '(column_name IS NOT NULL)' do produce any value. They can only be used as a boolean expression, as in CASE WHEN [expression] THEN 'true-value' ELSE 'false-value' END

Comment: This works beautifully for PostgreSQL, resulting in a boolean value.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN thevalue IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS newVal
FROM .... (rest of select)
```

I think it goes something like this

Actually, the ISNULL, may need to be WHEN thevalue IS NULL THEN 0

Comment: ISNULL() needs a second parameter in T-SQL: ISNULL(value, value-if-null)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to do a Convert(BIT, Value) of your result. Because something SQL will return an error that the value is not a boolean.

Comment: This little bit allowed me to have a where statement checking either 1 or 'true'

Comment: This results in true/null rather than true/false.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want 0,1 value as a return, and that we are talking about integer I would use the logic specified by [Torbjörn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177956/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-int-or-null-to-boolean-value-in-an-sql-query#177967) and wrap it in the function

```
create function dbo.isNotNull(@a int)
returns bit
as
begin
return isnull(@a-@a+1,0)
end
```

so then you can use it whenever you need by simply calling

```
select dbo.isNotNull(myIntColumn) from myTable
```

The answer provided by [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177956/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-int-or-null-to-boolean-value-in-an-sql-query#177987) is more universal though as it would work with any data type

Answer (score 2):

```
isnull(column - column + 1, 0) != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, assuming you use 0 for false and 1 for true:-

```
SELECT DECODE( col, NULL, 0, 1) FROM ...
```

You can also write this using the CASE syntax, but the above is idiomatic in Oracle.  DECODE is a bit like a switch/case; if col is NULL then 0 is returned, else 1.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted. Decode is the easiest and most concise representation of IF THEN ELSE.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when use 1, it means is true and else in other case.

So:

```
SELECT  IsDefault = CASE WHEN IsDefault = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

We can check if is null return "False" else return "True"

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(ColumnName<Nullable>, 'true')='false', 'true', 'false') ;


SELECT IIF(ISNULL(Email, 'true')='false', 'true', 'false') from Employee ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one I know for Oracle:

```
SELECT NVL2(nullableColumn, 1, 0) FROM someTable
```

`NVL2(value, ifNotNull, ifNull)` returns `ifNotNull` if the `value` is not null, and `ifNull` otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax works, but I had to figure out how to place it in my query. 
If OK, I'd like to share an example on how to fit into an extended query:

```
select count(*) as count, inventory,
CASE WHEN inventory = 0 THEN 'empty' ELSE 'not empty' END as InventoryStatus
from mytable group by count, inventory
```