# Creating a case expression with a join statement; Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need all `Library_ID` to return as either a yes or a no. They are either 1, 2, or 3 so I need to change everything that's a 1, 2, or 3 to yes and all others to no. Here is my statement so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Title, Publisher, Release_Date, ISBN, l.Library_ID
FROM  
    Catalog_Item c
INNER JOIN 
    Book b ON c.Catalog_Item_ID = b.Catalog_Item_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Physical_Item p ON c.Catalog_Item_ID = p.Catalog_Item_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Branch br ON p.Branch_ID = br.BRranch_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Library l ON br.Library_ID = l.Library_ID
ORDER BY 
    Title;
```

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/177956/1531971

Answer (score 3):

Is it as simple as this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Title, Publisher, Release_Date, ISBN,
    case when l.Library_ID in (1,2,3) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Library_ID
From ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below **CASE** expression:-

`SELECT DISTINCT 
    Title, Publisher, Release_Date, ISBN, l.Library_ID,
    CASE 
      WHEN l.Library_ID IN (1,2,3) THEN 'YES'
      ELSE 'NO'
    END AS "YES_OR_NO"
FROM

    Catalog_Item c
INNER JOIN 
    Book b ON c.Catalog_Item_ID = b.Catalog_Item_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Physical_Item p ON c.Catalog_Item_ID = p.Catalog_Item_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Branch br ON p.Branch_ID = br.BRranch_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Library l ON br.Library_ID = l.Library_ID
ORDER BY 
    Title;`